# Hashcodes - multiply or xor?

Tags: c#, gethashcode

I saw this hash function - and it triggered some alarms:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var result = 0;
    unchecked {
        result = anIntId.GetHashCode();
        result *= 397 * (aString != null ? aString.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

my automated hash-code-smell-fixer-subroutine wants to rewrite it to read:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    var result = 0;
    unchecked {
        result = anIntId.GetHashCode() * 397;
        result = (result * 397) ^ (aString != null ? aString.GetHashCode() : 0);
    }
    return result;
}
```

i can't remember where i learned this pattern, but it seems that some of it doesn't actually make sense:

- the first multiplication by 397 looks like a waste of time
- [redacted] {in brain minus coffee context, interpreted ^ to be exponentiation}

does this seem correct, or am i making some mistakes?

Comment: Math.Pow - exponentiation, ^ - xor

Comment: You shouldn't be using either multiplication or an XOR or exponentiation.  You should be using addition.

Comment: @Servy mind showing an addition based equivalent implementation as an answer?

Comment: @blueberryfields You replace the `*` before the generated hash code with a `+`.  You really need an answer to see how to do that?

Comment: @servy i thought something more complex than that. with a +, you're going to get way too many spurious collisions for my tastes

Comment: @blueberryfields No, you're not, because of the multiplication with the constant value.  That's the whole point of multiplying with a constant.  When you *only* multiply everything all of the constants are pointless.  When you alternate between addition and multiplication (even if every other value is a constant) it does a very good job of eliminating collisions.

Comment: Removed Resharper tag. Not my downvote btw.